# Science Fiction short story where humans are actually all female and men are women taken over by parasites

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

The details I can remember: Humans are naturally asexual, only women.  Penises are alien parasites attached at birth as part of a huge conspiracy. A group of women know the truth and are trying to fight back.  I believe the story ends with a woman giving birth to a daughter without having had sex.

Comment: What the hell? This sounds like something Chanty Binx would write... now I'm cautiously interested.

Comment: @SoConfused I’ve rolled back your edit, since it consisted of adding an answer, and answers shouldn’t be edited into the question itself; if you want to show that the answer has been found, you should write it down in the “Your Answer” box below instead (you can then also choose that answer as the correct answer so future visitors know that this was indeed what you were looking for). If you can find a link to the story (or a description of it), you should include that in the answer as well, to make it more complete.

Comment: This sounds like soft core porn for militant feminists :D If that came out today it would sell like crazy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is Manikins, by John Varley, according to the OP.

> "No, no." She laughed, without humor. "There's no such thing as a man, the way you're thinking about it. Only women who've been taken over at birth by these, these..." she groped in the air for a word hideous enough to express her distaste. She couldn't find it. "Things. Organisms. I said they invaded the Earth, but I'm not sure. They might be from here. There's no way to know, they've taken over too completely."
>
> -https://www.facebook.com/notes/sol-aris/manikins-by-john-varley-1976/10151440227880688/

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it. I would have *sworn* it was one of Tiptree's.